# Spring Rest Controller - Error 500 because service is null

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest

I have an endpoint like you can see below and if try GET http://localhost:8080/api/taxoffice/971/details in Postman, i'm recieving an error 400.

If i try GET http://localhost:8080/api/taxoffice/101/details then i'm getting an error 500 "Cannot invoke "com.walidatorpnr.taxoffice.service.TaxOffice_DetailService.findAllByTaxOfficeID(int)" because "this.taxOfficeDetailService" is null".

Records with both ids **are exist** in database.

Could you help me to fix this, please?

RestController

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/taxoffice")
public class TaxOfficeRestController {

 
    private final TaxOfficeService taxOfficeService;

    private final TaxOffice_DetailService taxOfficeDetailService;

    @Autowired
    public TaxOfficeRestController(TaxOfficeService taxOfficeService, TaxOffice_DetailService taxOfficeDetailService) {
    
        this.taxOfficeService = taxOfficeService;
        this.taxOfficeDetailService = taxOfficeDetailService;
    }

 List<TaxOffice> taxOffices = Lists.newArrayList();

 List<TaxOffice_Detail> taxOffice_details = Lists.newArrayList();

//Endpoint I have a problem with
  @GetMapping(value = "/{taxOffice_id}/details")
    private ResponseEntity<?> getTaxOfficeDetailsByTaxOfficeId(@PathVariable int taxOffice_id) {
    
        taxOffice_details = taxOfficeDetailService.findAllByTaxOfficeID(taxOffice_id);
        if(taxOffice_details.size() != 0) {
            for (TaxOffice_Detail taxOfficeDetail : taxOffice_details) {
                Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(TaxOfficeRestController.class).getTaxOfficeDetailsByTaxOfficeId(taxOffice_id)).withSelfRel();
               // Link relLink = linkTo(methodOn(TaxOfficeRestController.class).getTaxOfficeById(taxOffice_id)).withRel("Urząd skarbowy");
                taxOfficeDetail.add(selfLink);
               // taxOfficeDetail.add(relLink);
            }
            Link link = linkTo(methodOn(TaxOfficeRestController.class).getTaxOfficeDetailsByTaxOfficeId(taxOffice_id)).withSelfRel();
            CollectionModel<TaxOffice_Detail> result = CollectionModel.of(taxOffice_details, link);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(result);
        }
        else{
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        }

    }
```

TaxOffice_Details.java(i do not paste getters and setters here).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TaxOffice_Details")
public class TaxOffice_Detail extends RepresentationModel<TaxOffice_Detail> {

    public TaxOffice_Detail() {}

    public TaxOffice_Detail(int id, String street, String zipcode, String city, String phone, String fax, String email, String www) {
        this.id = id;
        this.street = street;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
        this.city = city;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.fax = fax;
        this.email = email;
        this.www = www;
    }

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "street")
    private String street;

    @Column(name = "zipcode")
    private String zipcode;

    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "fax")
    private String fax;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "www")
    private String www;

    @Transient
    private String taxoffice_name;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "taxOffice_id")
    private TaxOffice taxOffice;

   // @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "taxOffice_details")
    private List<TaxOffice> taxOffices;
    }
```

TaxOffice_DetailRepository

```
@Repository("taxOffice_DetailRepository")
public interface TaxOffice_DetailRepository extends JpaRepository<TaxOffice_Detail, Integer> {


    @Query("select t from TaxOffice_Detail t where t.id = :id")
    List<TaxOffice_Detail> findAllById(int id);

    @Query("select t from TaxOffice_Detail t where t.taxOffice.id = :taxOffice_id")
    List<TaxOffice_Detail> findAllByTaxOfficeId(int taxOffice_id);
    
}
```

TaxOffice_DetailService

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class TaxOffice_DetailService {

    final
    TaxOffice_DetailRepository taxOffice_detailRepository;

    public TaxOffice_DetailService(TaxOffice_DetailRepository taxOffice_detailRepository) {
        this.taxOffice_detailRepository = taxOffice_detailRepository;
    }

    public List<TaxOffice_Detail> findAllByID(int id) {
        return taxOffice_detailRepository.findAllById(id);
    }

    public List<TaxOffice_Detail> findAllByTaxOfficeID(int taxOffice_id) {
        return taxOffice_detailRepository.findAllByTaxOfficeId(taxOffice_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt that this is the full controller. The issue is with your request handling method, make it `public` instead of `private`. You have some AOP in there that proxies the controlle, `private` methods cannot be proxied thus the method is invoked on the proxy which doesn't have dependencies, instead of invoked and passed on to the actual instance. On a different note your controller is flawed as well, as you are keeping state (those lists) in your controller. What do you think happens when 10 requests come in to retrieve a list?

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you very much fort your help! IDE has this functionality that if you use a method that doesn't exist yet, but you are about to create it, it can generate that method(without implementation of course) for you.
I used this and unfortunately didn't notice that it generated the method as private....